# What is the optimal data structure for storing data points acquired during last n seconds

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, deque

I need a data structure (in C++), to store (integer,double) pair values acquired over last N seconds. The integer is a relative milliseconds time stamp (guaranteed to be monotonic) and the double is the actual data sample.

Constraints:

1. The number of points per second is not known apriori, but is not expected to vary much once the application is started. Typical value is 10 points per second.
2. The duration (i.e. N seconds) is also not known apriori and can change during execution. But when it is changed, I'm OK with flushing all data and starting fresh. Typical value is 60 seconds.
3. In every iteration, a new point is added to the end of the set and old points (i.e. older than N seconds from current time) are to be removed from the set.
4. I don't need fast random access, but fast insertions (tail) and deletions (head).

I am using std::deque at the moment, but I have a feeling that adding points at the tail end and deleting from the head end will cause frequent re-allocations.

Is there a standard way to do this? Or should I roll my own 'circular list' wrapper around std::vector?

Comment: better try tree. Or Lists.

Comment: from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque; "Insertion or removal of elements at the end or beginning - amortized constant O(1)" I dont think you will get better than this. The important question is how do you work with this data? For example is continuous access important?

Comment: "I have a feeling that adding points at the tail end and deleting from the head end will cause frequent re-allocations"

You have a feeling? `deque` is specifically made for fast insertions and deletions from the ends.

Comment: @rlbond : I was thinking 'ultimately'. For example, can I keep on adding one point at the end and deleting one point from the head so that the total number of items remain fixed? And this would be efficient - i.e. without frequent reallocations and movements?

Comment: Your idea to have a ''circular list' wrapper around std::vector', should be the right thing to do, to avoid memory allocations/deallocation (especially if you use msc)

Comment: @DieterLücking: I use gcc on Linux. But no C++11 support. What do you think of the 'add one point, delete one point' scenario? If I keep doing that, will the deque need to reallocate memory?

Comment: @Syam g++ uses buckets of 512 bytes, hence every 512 bytes you will have a deletion/allocation of a bucket

Comment: And why wouldn't a simple linked list work for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can use [circular buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html) from boost.
There is no equivalent in C++ STL.

If you don't want to depend on boost, implement a non-shrinking circular buffer yourself over std::vector, that's not hard.

Answer (score 2):

For "fast insertions (tail) and deletions (head)" `std::deque` is optimal, given that it's amortized O(1) both insertion and deletion at both ends. You could also use `std::queue`. The standard library doesn't provide anything more "efficient" with the given requirements.

Comment: But won't the deque ultimately need reallocation when a new point is added even though the number of points does not increase (because one or more points are deleted from the head)?

Comment: @Syam Implementation defined.

Comment: A warning regarding msvc: It has a ridiculous tiny _DEQUESIZ of 16 and  performs like a list for sizeof(T) > 8